# Blog only showing one post even though more published

Tags: posts, wp-query

Why is my wordpress blog.php only showing one blog entry while I have two entrys in the blog at present and have checked both are published and they are and yes i do have my reading setup to my blog page any ideas?.

http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/

```
<?php /* Template Name: BlogPosts */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="contentWrap" class="group">

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <div id="article">
        <?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>


            <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p> Posted By <?php the_author(); ?></p>

                <div id="entryItem">
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div><!--entryItem-->      

        </div><!--article-->
<?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!--contentWrap-->

</div><!--mainWrapper-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: To me it seems that there are three posts there?

Comment: I actually solved it

Comment: Nice! I suggest you answer your own question and describe what you did. Good for the site.